# Why are some vaccines 100% effective while others aren’t?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, vaccine, rabies, covid

Why are some vaccines, like for rabies, 100% effective at treating someone while others, like the covid 19 vaccine, isn’t.

Disclaimer: not a dumb vaccine skeptic or anything just genuinely curious.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help]. On this site, we have a requirement for the questions to contain some evidence that the asker has attempted to answer it for themselves.

Comment: Where did you get the fact that the Rabies vaccine has 100% efficacy at **treating someone**? Could you please provide evidence? This example and other [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], state why we require prior research information when asking questions as well as in in answers.

Comment: It's true that the rabies vaccine is 100% effective when given prior to the appearance of symptoms, but after symptoms appear its efficacy immediately drops to 0%. That interesting fact probably speaks to one of the reasons why some vaccines are more effective than others. Those are the kind of facts you would have found doing some prior research on this question. You need to provide a supporting reference for your claim of 100% efficacy (should be easy), and adding another link mentioning that the 100% efficacy only applies prior to appearance of symptoms would make a much better question.